# What is the value of this logarithmic expression

Tags: logarithms

I am new to logarithms, and I need to find out the value this expression.

$ \ Given, \\x=\sqrt{log_{11}7}\\y=\sqrt{log_711} \\find :  e^{y \ln{7} -x \ln{11}} $

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $log_a b=\frac {log_c b} {lob_c a}$, using this formula we get
$$e^{\sqrt {\frac {ln\, 11} {ln \,7}}\cdot ln \, 7 -\sqrt {\frac {ln\, 7} {ln \,11}}\cdot ln \, 11  }$$

considering only the Exponent we have
$$\sqrt{\frac{\ln(11)\ln(7)^2}{\ln(7)}}-\sqrt{\frac{\ln(7)\ln(11)^2}{\ln(11)}}=0$$
after cancelling. Now the expression equals $\ e^0 \ \\ $ Therefore answer is $1$

Comment: This is the combination, full procedure.

Comment: I just completed the answer just to make stuff a little easy. I regret spoiling any fun! :)

Answer (score 1):

considering only the Exponent we have
$$\sqrt{\frac{\ln(11)\ln(7)^2}{\ln(7)}}-\sqrt{\frac{\ln(7)\ln(11)^2}{\ln(11)}}=0$$
after cancelling. Therefore your term is $1$

Answer (score 1):

Since $log_a b=\frac {log_c b} {lob_c a}$, using this formula we get
$$e^{\sqrt {\frac {ln\, 11} {ln \,7}}\cdot ln \, 7 -\sqrt {\frac {ln\, 7} {ln \,11}}\cdot ln \, 11  }$$
I guess you can finish it from here.

Comment: The finished answer is below ☺

Comment: I wanted to give you just the piece of information I thought you were missing and not spoil the fun part afterwards :)

Comment: Oh no! Was it like that? I missed the fun part afterwards  I'm so sorry and will try not to spoil such fun parts in future!